# Stop navigation from navigation controller swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

i have a navigation controller from login page, and after login successful, i would like to dismiss the navigation which mean user are not allow to go back to the login page once login successful. I have tried to create another storyboard and perform segue, but the navigation bar still persist, anyway to dismiss navigation bar programmatically or from storyboard? 
[image]

i would not want the "Pairing" button to appear on this page.

Comment: Don't present a new view controller at the existing navigation controller or present it as a root controller if you want to disable back navigation, otherwise you'll have to deal not only with the standard back button but also with an edge gesture. Not to mention it is going to be hella confusing for a user.\

Comment: if i don't present a new view controller then i apply another UIView on top of my existing view controller and stack all the way for my apps?

Comment: Then the purpose of navigation controller is not clear. Replace it with an ordinary UIViewController at the stage where you don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution!

I tested it on iOS 11 and iOS 13 and it works fine :)

```
protocol CustomNavigationViewControllerDelegate {
    func shouldPop() -> Bool
}

class CustomNavigationViewController: UINavigationController, UINavigationBarDelegate {
    var backDelegate: CustomNavigationViewControllerDelegate?

    func navigationBar(_ navigationBar: UINavigationBar, shouldPop item: UINavigationItem) -> Bool {
        return backDelegate?.shouldPop() ?? true
    }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, CustomNavigationViewControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        (self.navigationController as? CustomNavigationViewController)?.backDelegate = self
    }

    func shouldPop() -> Bool {
        if (needToShowAlert) {
            showExitAlert()
            return false

        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Segue to the navigation controller from the Login page, rather than from the navigation controller to the Login page.